# Abstract state with template in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am working with ui-router AngularJS in Ionic Project. I have an abstract state where I nest my children's templates via `<ion-nav-view>` tag. The question is can I display some default data in the template of the abstract state that will be shown for all the children's templates ?? If no then Why. I tried this simple example

```
<ion-view view-title="MyView">
  <div>
   <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <ion-nav-view name="ChildContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-view>
```

But the message Welcome is not shown. The space for the div is there but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. What I ended with to not repeat the same info within all the children templates is to create a custom directive with its own template and just include this directive in every child's template. So, we just have one place to manipulate. It is the section "Template-expanding directive" in Angular documentation. More informations could be found in this link : [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Hope it will help someone else :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can define a controller for your abstract state and there setear default values that can be displayed in various other views. You can also do this in the function

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
})

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.title = "Test title";
})
```

OR

```
angular.module('started.controllers', [])

.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.title = "Test title";
});

<ion-view view-title="{{title}}">
   <div>
     <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <ion-nav-view name="ChildContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for your response but my problem is that the welcome is not displayed not the variables linked to the scope the welcome text is not displayed in the children's views.

Comment: According to what I know, the values of the variables are only $ scope controllers and their contents. If you want to generate a variable that you can access from any controller, you must be $rootScope or generate some kind of service that you deliver those values. $rootScope is the root that can reach only manage MySQL from any field of your app, $ scope is descended therefore belongs to any controller.

Comment: I used to put the whole thing between <ion-content> Welcome message and <ion-nav-view> </ion-content> but then I see the welcome message but not the content of the children's view.

Comment: But that does not correspond, the order is <ion-view> <ion content> </ ion content> </ ion-view>

Comment: Yes I mean <ion-view> <ion content> Welcome message and <ion-nav-view> </ ion content> </ ion-view>.